# Gsub a every element after a keyword in R

Tags: r, string, gsub, string-substitution

I'd like to remove all elements of a string after a certain keyword. 
Example :

```
this.is.an.example.string.that.I.have
```

Desired Output :

```
This.is.an.example
```

I've tried using `gsub('string', '', list)` but that only removes the word string. I've also tried using the `gsub('^string', '', list)` but that also doesn't seem to work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following simple `sub` may help you here.

```
sub("\\.string.*","",variable)
```

***Explanation:*** Method of using `sub`

```
sub(regex_to_replace_text_in_variable,new_value,variable)
```

***Difference between `sub` and `gsub`:***

`sub`: is being used for performing substitution  on variables.

`gsub`: `gsub` is being used for same substitution tasks only but only thing it will be perform substitution on ALL matches found though `sub` performs it only for first match found one.

***From help page of*** `R`***:***

> sub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
>       fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
>
> gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
>        fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this positive lookbehind regex

```
S <- 'this.is.an.example.string.that.I.have'
gsub('(?<=example).*', '', S, perl=TRUE)
# 'this.is.an.example'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strsplit`. Here you split your string after a key word, and retain the first part of the string.

```
x <- "this.is.an.example.string.that.I.have"
strsplit(x, '(?<=example)', perl=T)[[1]][1]

[1] "this.is.an.example"
```